# Prevent showing dll source on exceptions

Tags: c#, dll

I have some custom build dll libraries that I have build them myself. Obviously I have some error handling in my code and I throw custom exceptions

```
If(Error)
     throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
```

The problem is that when an application uses the library and an exception that I have defined is thrown, Visual studio shows the source code of dll library at the point that exception is thrown.

Is there a way to prevent showing the source code that visual studio show the break point to the application itself, i.e. the method that is called that causes this exception?

**Example:**
If `System.File.WriteAllText` throws exception the code does not show the source code of `System.IO.dll` it throws the exception on my own code

Comment: Don't break when exception is thrown than (somewhere in exception/debug settings)... Not sure what exactly you are trying to prevent.

Comment: Is it showing your source or is it showing decompiled code? I.e. are local variable names and comments preserved?

Comment: Pretty important it works this way, shows you what *really* went wrong.  Strange that you don't want to know.  Just remove the library from the project and add a reference to the Release build of the DLL.  Its stripped PDB file ensures that the debugger cannot find the source code anymore and is forced to show the caller's code.  Using [attributes] is an option as well but that gets boring too quickly.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, its not strange as I'm not offering my library as open source, and simply I don't want the user be able to copy my source code, so using the release build will solve the problem, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot. If you write it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: There is a pretty heavy duh-factor here.  Don't deploy the source code of the library.to the user's machine and he won't have anything to look at or copy.  Decompiling .NET assemblies is pretty easy, what you really want is an obfuscator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Hans Passant Suggested. I must use the Release version of the dll to hide the source code from being shown.

Comment: I had the same issue and been looking for an answer for hours. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) or [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) over the method/class/property that contains the code you don't want exception to fire.

Comment: I want exception to fire, that's why I have written it. for example If `System.File.WriteAllText` throws exception the code does not show the source code of `System.IO.dll` it throws the exception on my own code

Answer (score 0):

You have to define DLL in another solution, and don't open that project in VS.
Then you should reference compiled DLL file and remove PDB file from that directory.

Comment: well I'm exactly doing that

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani and you are deleted PDB file?

Comment: well I'm copying dll to my new project folder, so there will be no pdb files there